# sql calculation save result in temp column and pas it to another calculation

Tags: sql-server, calculator

how do i make sql calculate and pass the result to a temp column and then use that result in another calculation with some values from another tabel and then pass that result to a temp column

as i getting

> Invalid column name 'inch'.

```
 SELECT 10 AS inch
 SELECT inch *25.4 AS diameter
SELECT P.[merged],
(P.[profile]*2+diameter)*PI() AS circumference 
 FROM  [dbo].[profilelist] P;
```

i can get it to work with this

```
SELECT 10 AS inch
select 10*25.4 as diameter
SELECT P.[merged],
(P.[profile] *2+254)*PI() as circumference

  FROM [dbo].[profilelist] P;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for.

```
Declare @inch int, @diameter decimal(5,2)
SELECT @inch=10
SELECT @diameter = @inch * 25.4
SELECT P.[merged],
(P.[profile]*2+@diameter)*PI() AS circumference 
 FROM  [dbo].[profilelist] P;
```

Comment: that will work but are there anyway to do it so you can see the multiple results? like the result from diameter and circumference

Comment: Select the variables. IE. `Select @inch, @diameter, etc.`

Comment: are there any way to pass `SELECT P.[merged],@circumference=P.[profile]*2+@diameter)*PI() AS circumference `
to another calculation as it only shows 1 column

Comment: Create another variable for merged (`@merged`), then you can pass both merged and circumference to the next calculation.

Comment: You may want to think about creating functions to do these calculations.

Comment: i had also tried with tha as `Select @circumference=P.[profile]*2+@diameter)*PI()   FROM  [dbo].[profilelist] P;
select @circumference as circumference`